# Docker - Running bash scripts on a Windows host

Tags: django, bash, perl, docker

I setup a django project with Docker, its got two containers, one for the `django` server, one for the `postgres` server. I want to be able to also do different things like run bash scripts and perl scripts for this project, for example I need to use a bash script to download and restore database dumps from the live site automatically. Do I setup a new Docker image for each bash script? Or would I need to setup a Ubuntu container and run the bash scripts through that?

Heres the Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.5

ENV PYTHONBUFFERED 1
ENV APPLICATION_ROOT /app/
ENV APP_ENVIRONMENT L
COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=1

RUN mkdir -p $APPLICATION_ROOT
WORKDIR $APPLICATION_ROOT
ADD requirements.txt $APPLICATION_ROOT
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ADD . $APPLICATION_ROOT
```

And the docker-compose file:

```
web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
        - .:/app
    ports:
        - "8998:8998"
    links:
        - db

db:
    image: postgres:9.4
    environment:
        APP_ENVIRONMENT: L
        POSTGRES_USER: postgres
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: root
        POSTGRES_DB: mydb
```

I'm new to Docker so don't yet know the best approach to doing things. Where would I put the bash script and new docker file, and how would I link it to this project so that I can execute the scripts whenever the project is running? Theres a few ways I can do this, I could just create a bash container, and use it to run the scripts. Or I could make a container built on a bash image which holds all the scripts I'll need, or I could make a container for each one of them. I might need to run `perl` or `awk` or `expect` alongside these bash scripts, so in that case, would I just import an image for each of these into the container?

Answer (score 1):

You've got some concepts wrong:

1. You only load one image per container. The container runs an instance of that image. Think of the container as a contained virtual machine and of the image as an OS.
2. You don't want one container per script. Containers are contained, if you run a script in one of them it won't affect another container. You could have many ubuntu images, of course, but it just doesn't make sense for what you want to do. Think of a container as a service that has to perform a task (run a database, host a webpage, etc); it has to have inside everything it needs to work.
3. If you need to run a script in a container, you have to first provision it to the container using `ADD`or `COPY` in your Dockerfile, and then `CMD` to execute the script. That will execute it inside the container, and therefore will affect its state. Check the [Dockerfile reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/%20%22Dockerfile%20reference) for more info on how to use these commands.

Comment: Also, since you seem to have some troubles understanding the whole container architecture, I'd suggest taking a look at the get-started docs.